# ARM template MSDeploy error

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am using ARM template to deploy a set of resources. Sometimes (not always), my deployment fails with an error "Deployment was interrupted and the process running it was terminated unexpectedly". This error occurs when ARM template is run through Powershell, as well as when running the ARM template through Visual Studio.

I have also checked for the race condition and have set up a dependency on MSDeploy in appsettings/connectionstrings/web config settings. When looking at the appManagerLog.xml on kudu portal, I can see an error "Failed to download package". My package.zip file is present as an Azure Blob, and the same blob sometimes works and sometimes fails.

Any references for solving this ?

Comment: VS uses PowerShell to deploy - so that's probably a wash... how are you staging the package for ARM?  Is it public or behind sas?  How long does the deployment generally take?  Are you able to download the package.zip after the deployment says it fails?  What do the ARM logs say about the failure?

Comment: I am uploading the package as a zip file to blob, which is public. In the arm template, I am writing the url as the packageUri parameter of the MSDeploy resource. Deployment generally takes 3-4 minutes. Yes, I am able to download the package after it days download failed. The log first says that the deployment failed and likely cause is a race condition, going down it gives an error "Failed to download package", "AppGallery deploy failed"

Comment: Not sure what it would be racing with, but it sounds like a bug - if you can get a repro to hang onto (i.e. leave the deployment in the failed state) open a support req in the portal...

Comment: @V.G.: Did you find solution for this?